# Initialize local static const variable with global extern const value

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
extern const uint32_t gMask_00FF00FF;
static inline void Filter_32_alpha() {
    static const uint32_t mask = gMask_00FF00FF;
}
```

My program uses the above code in a multithreaded environment.

The 'mask' variable above did not seem to initialize correctly in multithreaded.

Removing the 'static const' preceding the variable will cause the problem to appear to have been removed.

I wonder if this is the right change.

Comment: ordering of static-lifetime objects in not guaranteed between translation units. google "schwartz counter" for a means of guaranteeing it.

Comment: initialization of function local static variables is not thread safe prior to c++11